# Data from component.ts is not fetched in component.html in angular application

Tags: angular, subscribe

I have written a simple angular application that will get fetch the data from REST Api and plot the Pie Chart.
In my app.component.ts file I am getting data like this

```
 this.satisfactionService.getGenderDetails().subscribe(result =>{ 

   this.Data=result;  

   console.log(this.Data)
   console.log(Object.keys(this.Data).length)
   console.log(this.Data.labels)
   console.log(this.Data.values) 

   this.flag=true;

   console.log(this.Data)

   if (typeof(this.Data) != "undefined") {   

     this.pieChartLabels = this.Data.labels;
     this.pieChartData=this.Data.values;
     this.pieChartType= 'pie';

     console.log(this.pieChartLabels )
     console.log(this.pieChartData)

     this.flag=false;
   }

 }, error => console.log(error));
```

In my app.component.html file I am plotting pie chart based on the data

```
<div class="otherBox" >
  <div class="vamBox">
    <div style="text-align:center;">     
      <span>
        <p class="cardText">Distribution of Students Based on Gender</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vamInfoBox">
    <canvas baseChart height="100px"
      [data]="pieChartData"
      [labels]="pieChartLabels"
      [chartType]="pieChartType">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this error when debugging using Chrome tools
[image]

Comment: Are you passing the correct data format of the chart which is needed

Comment: I think your component is loading before your data fetches using REST. So try to load data in the constructor/onNgInit so it would make sure that data object is loaded before using it.

Comment: I am loading the data in the constructor only.

Comment: Try adding `*ngIf="pieChartData"` to the vamInfoBox div. Maybe the chart tries to access the data in a specific format before the REST callback returns the actual data

Comment: @LennartHoffmann I added *ngIf='pieChartData' to both div and the canvas but still getting the error. I suspect the issue in subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the Data is fetched after the component tries to render the Chart,
you can add a simple ****ngIf*** directive to check if the ***pieChartDate*** is available

```
<canvas *ngIf='pieChartData'></canvas>
```

Comment: I added *ngIf='pieChartData' but still facing the error. I think the issue is with the subscribe method in component.ts.

Answer (score 0):

angular is telling u that it doesnt know "data" its probably related to not installing the plugin using npm. Or if u do share the app.module.ts so that we see where you made mistake. Although if you use lazy loading remember to put `.forRoot()` after your installed import!

Comment: I have imported the chartmodule in app.module.ts. Where should I use forRoot()?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding a boolean variable after it comes of the subscription loop in component.ts file `this.flag=true;` In my component.html I did `<div class="vamInfoBox" *ngIf="!flag">` and this solved the issue. Thank you @Zouhair and @LennartHoffmann for giving me the hint.